# How to establish a simple ssh connection with c++

Tags: c++, ssh, visual-studio-2015, libssh

I am trying to make a c++ program which will connect to an ssh server (my laptop). The server is ok because I can get connected via putty. Although the program I wrote so far can not. In my code I am using the library libssh.h and for development I used visual studio 2015. The error I get is: **crypt_set_algorithms2: no crypto algorithm function found for 3des-cbc**
I haven't found anything so far so I hope to your help. 
The code I use:

```
#include <libssh/libssh.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
int main()
{
    ssh_session my_ssh_session;
    int rc;
    int port = 22;
    int verbosity = SSH_LOG_PROTOCOL;
    char *password;
    // Open session and set options
    my_ssh_session = ssh_new();
    if (my_ssh_session == NULL)
        exit(-1);
    ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST, "192.168.1.6");
    ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_USER, "john");
    ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_LOG_VERBOSITY, &verbosity);
    ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_CIPHERS_C_S,"aes128-ctr");

    //ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_PORT, &port);
    // Connect to server
    rc = ssh_connect(my_ssh_session);
    if (rc != SSH_OK)  
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session)); //HERE IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR 
        ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
        exit(-1);
    }
    // Verify the server's identity
    // For the source code of verify_knowhost(), check previous example
/*  if (verify_knownhost(my_ssh_session) < 0)
    {
        ssh_disconnect(my_ssh_session);
        ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
        exit(-1);
    }
*/  
    // Authenticate ourselves
    password = "pass";
    rc = ssh_userauth_password(my_ssh_session, NULL, password);
    if (rc != SSH_AUTH_SUCCESS)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error authenticating with password: %s\n",
            ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session));
        ssh_disconnect(my_ssh_session);
        ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
        exit(-1);
    }


        ssh_disconnect(my_ssh_session);
    ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use different cipher. `3des-cbc` is broken and probably disabled on your server already.

There is really [nice tutorial](http://api.libssh.org/master/libssh_tutor_guided_tour.html) with simple session.

Removing the line makes it working for me on Ubuntu (don't know where you found it):

```
ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_CIPHERS_C_S,"aes128-ctr");
```

If not, what version of `libssh` are you using? Isn't it some obsolete one?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Firstly I removed the line you mentioned but nothing happened. In my project I used the libssh 0.7.1. After your answer I tried the version 0.7.0 but I got an error that msvcr120d.dll is missing. After I downloaded and pasted it in my project path I got an error that the  application could not start properly.

Comment: I found I used some Ubuntu-ancient `libssh-6.3`, so this will probably not be a problem. So the question is what is the server on the other side. Are you able to connect there with some recent openssh?

Answer (score 2):

Finally got it! I removed the line

```
ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_CIPHERS_C_S,"aes128-ctr");
```

Then I used the ssh.dll from libssh **v0-7.2** instead of the ssh.dll of **v0-7.1** I used before. The ssh.dll is located in *libssh-0.7.2\bin*. If you take an error like the **msvcr120d.dll** is missing try to change from debug to release in visual studio.