# How to link .so file to a cpp program

Tags: c++, ssh, libssh2, .so

I have libssh2.so.1.0.1(.so) binary on my local machine and I don't have any header files present on my machine.

This is the basic ssh program I have been trying to connect to my server through ssh protocol.
Reference: [How to establish a simple ssh connection with c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33789213/how-to-establish-a-simple-ssh-connection-with-c)

Now I am unable to link library (libssh2.so.1.0.1) to the below sample program.

Following is the sample program I have written and followed by errors.

sshsample.cpp:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
int main()
{
    ssh_session my_ssh_session;
    int rc;
    int port = 22;
    int verbosity = SSH_LOG_PROTOCOL;
    char *password;
    // Open session and set options
    my_ssh_session = ssh_new();
   if (my_ssh_session == NULL)
   exit(-1);
   ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST, "192.168.1.6");
   ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_USER, "john");
   ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_LOG_VERBOSITY, &verbosity);
   // Connect to server
   rc = ssh_connect(my_ssh_session);
   if (rc != SSH_OK)  
   {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session));  
    ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
    exit(-1);
}
// Authenticate ourselves
password = "pass";
rc = ssh_userauth_password(my_ssh_session, NULL, password);
if (rc != SSH_AUTH_SUCCESS)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error authenticating with password: %s\n",
    ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session));
    ssh_disconnect(my_ssh_session);
    ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
    exit(-1);
    }
  ssh_disconnect(my_ssh_session);
  ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
}
```

I have compiled the above file with below command

```
g++ -L. -llibssh2 -o main sshsample.cpp
```

but I get the following error

```
sshsample.cpp: In function 'int main()':
sshsample.cpp:8: error: 'ssh_session' was not declared in this scope
sshsample.cpp:8: error: expected `;' before 'my_ssh_session'
sshsample.cpp:11: error: 'SSH_LOG_PROTOCOL' was not declared in this scope
sshsample.cpp:14: error: 'my_ssh_session' was not declared in this scope
sshsample.cpp:14: error: 'ssh_new' was not declared in this scope
```

Any suggestions/help would be of great use

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: try `-lssh2` instead of `libssh2`. Also make sure the library is in your current directory if running `-L.` you also need to include a header to include libraries, because it's not going to know what you mean if you just link the library and continue to not declare it in your code.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the libssh2 header file into your compilation units where ssh APIs are invoked. You cannot expect the compiler to resolve what an `ssh_session` is without this.  If you have the library properly installed, you should have access to the header files to invoke it.

`#include <libssh2.h>`

Edit: Honestly the APIs you are using in your example belong to the original libssh library I don't see anything in your example that would need to link with libssh2.

`#include <libssh/libssh.h>`